# How can I add perspective to something using Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I was trying to recreate this kind of image in Adobe Illustrator.

[image]

I had tried perspective grid tools in Illustrator as well as blend options, but couldn't get the proper result.  How can I create this using the perspective tool?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As [Scott already mentioned](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/20305/408), you want to draw this flat first. Drawing in perspective is much more difficult, and why put yourself through it if you don't have to?

I created this first:

[image]

I then grouped these shapes together and made copies of it (in order to create one long horizontal shape).

Now I know you mentioned you've worked with the perspective tool before, but try the following:

Go to `View -> Perspective Grid`. This should bring up a perspective grid like so:

[image]

Now select your shape and go to `Object -> Perspective -> Attach to Active Plane` and then use the `Perspective Selection Tool` <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> and drag your shape around. You should see it conform to the current plane. Now simple adjust to taste.

[image]

There you go! You can always hide/show the grid again by pressing <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>

The perspective tool may seem pretty complex and scary at first, but once you get used to it is incredibly useful. Make sure you do some more research about it to get the most out of it, because it really is the best way to build shapes with perspective.

Further reading:

- [About Perspective Grid](http://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/perspective-grid.html)
- [Adobe Video Tutorial on Perspective
  Grid](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/learn-illustrator-cs5/defining-perspective-grids/)

And if you have a Lynda subscription...

- [Deke McClelland's Perspective Drawing Video Tutorials](http://www.lynda.com/Illustrator-CS5-tutorials/one-on-one-mastery/61022-2.html?srchtrk=index:10%0Alinktypeid:2%0Aq:perspective%20grid%0Apage:1%0As:relevance%0Asa:true%0Aproducttypeid:2) (See chapter 28)

Answer (score 3):

Draw the shapes flat. Then use the **Free Transform** Tool or `Object > Envelope Distort > Distort with Warp` to create the perspective appearance.

Comment: i have no concern about blue portion;i have problem regarding white rounded rectangle

Comment: @Sumann - As I posted, draw everything **flat** then distort it.

Comment: scott could you tell under which style in wrap option

Comment: Any of them. Pick any, set the "Bend" to 0 and then adjust the Horizontal slider.

Comment: While this is a quick solution Scott, the biggest issue is that the "further away something is" the more stretched out the details get, which is contrary to how perspective actually works. You can see an example [here](http://i.imgur.com/iWelbtQ.png). So it works well for simple shapes and object, but not for anything that has any sort of detail inside of it.