# How are designers creating the 3d effect often seen on sites like dribble lately for displaying portfolio screens?

Tags: portfolio

I am seeing it a lot lately and I'm curious what tools are being used for this technique, is it an actual 3d app, or photoshop?
Here is an example:
http://dribbble.com/shots/1160245-iPad-UI-Files?list=users

Comment: Possible duplicate: [**How to achieve this 3D “Card” effect**](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/20597/8708)

Comment: These images are cool looking, and can definitely impress other designers and people taking a quick glance at your work, but don't use these to present your work in your portfolio. As a collage in a banner or something somewhere, or as a generic stock-like graphic to go with a blog article they're great, but for an employer these don't present your work well, as it's more of a pretty picture made out of screenshots of guis.

Answer (score 0):

You could use either Photoshop, Illustrator or a 3D app to accomplish this. My guess is that Photoshop would be the tool of choice for the example you linked to.

Both PS and AI have 3D menus in recent versions so this isn't terribly difficult to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some basic photoshop work.

1. grab a ss of the work you want rendered
2. go to edit->transform->free transform->rotate it a bit, 45 degrees or so
3. go to edit->transform->perspective tool->play with it, reduce the width of the top portion.
4. go to edit->transform->free transform->reduce the height to make up for some weird, unrealistic skewy side effect of the perspective too.

Done, now you have your image at an angle.

To make it float above something:

1. repeat above with a second image that's on a layer below your work
2. add a large drop shadow with appropraite distance, size, and choke to the top object that's floating.

To render it as 3d:

1. Take the top object and duplicate the layer, move the new copy down a pixel, maybe even down and over a pixel, but you'll want to keep the ratio of copies down or up: copies moved over consistent.
2. duplicate the layer you just moved and do it again.

This is a cheep sounding method, but it works quite well. Repeat for however many pixels you want to extrude it.