# How to create 3D presentational mockup templates to showcase logo design to a client?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, mockup

I would like to know how to create a 3D presentational mockup template that utilizes smart objects to change dynamically for example logo design. I would like to know also tricks on how to add shadows that dynamically adjust to the content of the smart object.

Example:

```
http://graphicriver.net/item/stationery-branding-mockup/9186667?WT.oss_phrase=&WT.oss_rank=2&WT.z_author=MassDream&WT.ac=search_thumb
```

I  can't find any tutorials on how to do such a things.

Comment: In 3D you can search for uv mapping (eg. on boxes or books). In 2D you can apply a template and a perspective.

Comment: Thank you. Can you suggest a good free and paid programs that can handle that ? I have an original Adobe CS6 but didn't see any program that would handle the 3D work. When it comes to 2D can you elaborate more on the template and perspective topics ? Thanks :)

Comment: Any help will be apprecieated :)...

Comment: Hi there! Is this useful? http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20597/how-to-achieve-this-3d-card-effect?lq=1

Comment: If you are already skilled on 2D editing, I suggest you to start from @Yisela and Harut suggestions: you can use 2D to *emulate* 3D. If you want to use a 3D software...there is a [whole world](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_3D_modeling_software).

Comment: @Yisela Yes, that's quite useful but still too generic on the step-by-step process.

Comment: @PaoloGibellini Thanks Paolo ! Wow, indeed it's like a whole new land to explore. Thanks a lot ! I think 3D graphics and Vector graphics are what is being used to generate such templates.

Comment: relevant and an attempt at a blanket answer: [How to mockup a logo in a realistic environment?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/113783/how-to-mockup-a-logo-in-a-realistic-environment)

Answer (score 1):

There are templates for this that you just apply your design to.
Here are some...
http://designbump.com/30-branding-mockups-psd-templates/

Comment: Can you please add some more informations? Suppose the linked side is down no reader can understand your answer ...

Comment: I know that there are tons of free templates avaible on the internet but the thing is that I want to learn how to do it. Simply to expand my current knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I fully understand your question and what you mean by "change dynamically". If you want to know how to make a smart object mockup, here it is:

```
1.Create a new document and select Shape Tool or press "U"
2.Add a rectangle shape on your canvas with dimensions you need
3.Right-click on the shape layer and click "Convert to Smart Object"
4.Now double-click on thumbnail of the layer.
5.This will open a new .PSB document which is the container of your smart object. 
6.Draw your logo in this document and press Ctrl+S.
```

That's it. Now you can get back to your main document and see the changes. You can deform your smart object or apply filters. To change perspective go to  Edit -> Transform -> Perspective.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks ! Will surely check that one out. I have additional question. What if for example I want to add some objects like clippers or pencils to the mockup along with flyers, business cards etc. to make it look more naturally ? Or an ipad for example displaying logo on it's screen.