# How to create mockup like this?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design, 3d, mockup

[image]

What is the normal process to create mockups like this? Are they created in 3D and then in photoshop?

Would be a great help if you guys can help me.

Comment: These particular ones look like photos. If they're not, they're probably made in more specialist 3D software (though just taking photos would be so much easier, cheaper and more realistic...). If you're interested in putting 2D designs on 3D mockups, check out http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20597/how-to-achieve-this-3d-card-effect/39083#39083 and the questions it links to

Comment: Well i have tried to create them in photoshop but i honestly don't know where to start one thing i do know though is that these are created in 3D as i asked the creator himself but how he did it i don't know.

Answer (score 2):

If you have 'real' objects to include in your images, you would be much better off using proper 3D software, as Photoshop is not designed for 3D. Blender is a completely free open-source project that has been developed for many years, is highly stable, runs on any platform, and is a viable alternative to $x000 applications like Maya. Once you start to use Blender, you will never even *consider* Photoshop again when you hear the word '3D'. Check out [Blender.org](http://www.blender.org/features/)

Comment: [I disagree with you on Photoshop isn't designed for 3D](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/how-to/create-3d-models.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can start by creating a small lightbox with white nylon, a simple blank sheet, a adjustable light, a tripod along with a smart phone or professional DSLR camera. There are plenty of DIY videos available how to do that. Take a look here: [How to make a mini photo studio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pHcrmQrp7u8). 
Of course creating your own little studio requires some extra work. You’ll find  affordable photo studio kit solutions for under $50 on eBay.

Comment: You can find them for under $50 on Amazon, too (a more trustworthy source than eBay has become)

Answer (score 1):

There is no doubt that such mockups are created using dedicated 3D Software, I had personally started Blender to make my own style of mockups to further use on the Photoshop since the Blender is open-source and very light program to explore possibilities for 3D illustration.

Answer (score -1):

Usually for branding mockups you can just download PSDs like [here](http://designbump.com/30-branding-mockups-psd-templates/) and [here](http://inspirationhut.net/design-resources/collection-high-quality-free-branding-mockup-psd-downloads/).
Or just search for *"PSD identity/brand mockup"* there are hundreds of files, and they are usually very easy to use.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. I believe the OP is asking how to *create* these mockups, not how to put their own work on the mockups