# How can I create perspective in Sketch 3

Tags: sketch-app, perspective, presentation-design

Is it possible to create perspective in Sketch 3?

Example:

[image]

In Photoshop, I would use a perspective tool, but I'm not sure how to do this in Sketch 3.

On a related note, are there any useful tutorials on presenting your work with different perspective techniques similar to those used on Behance and/or Dribbble?

Comment: use the [Transform](http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/support/documentation/04-shapes/3-transform.html) tool in Sketch?

Comment: Thanks! That is what I was looking for...somehow I overlooked that.

Comment: For the 3D Card effect, you can check out this thread [How to achieve this 3D “Card” effect](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20597/how-to-achieve-this-3d-card-effect). However this was done in Photoshop and Illustrator. I am sure you can find a similar solution.

Comment: I find the Transform tool really difficult to use.  Any better alternatives that do not require a subscription?

Comment: @kwahn Keep practicing... Or download a (free) template and put your work in it.

Comment: This isnt perspecituve at all ist just isometric

Answer (score 4):

There is a preset out there for sketch which will target a given element (mockup) and transform your layout onto that mockup, allowing for very fast concept-to-mockup production - it's called "angle" and I've found it pretty effective.

https://designcode.io/angle

It includes a huge library of both target mockup devices and angles and of common screen backgrounds etc (see image below) makes the whole process a lot smoother.

It also works on any element you've drawn and chosen prior to invoking the plugin - so draw your own rectangle and then transform it, and the plugin will apply your layout to it. Perfect for those business card images.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are some ways you could go for:

1. You can transform your layers in Sketch:

   - Move the points of an element to create a "fake 3D" effect (perspective deformation)
   - > The Transform tool can be used to distort an existing vector shape by skewing the points or by creating a fake 3D effect. You can use the Transform tool in Sketch to transform one or multiple layers at the same time. ([transform](https://www.sketchapp.com/docs/shapes/transform/))
2. One way would be to export your screens to Photoshop.
3. Plugins like [Magic Sketch](https://magicsketch.io/mirror) could also help

Comment: Don't really see how this answers the question by doing the work and then moving it to Photoshop.  If you'd like to expand on what you're referring to with `transform` post an example and I will remove my downvote.  Adding sorry also discredits your answer, for me, as a solution to the question.

Comment: A revision of my answer was necessary. Sorry for the low stakes.

Comment: Answer is somewhat better so I removed my down vote.  If you posted an example with Sketch I will up vote your answer.