# How to create 3d text or photo based logo

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3d, texture

I am completely new to Photoshop and now I am able to create simple logo based on images available or creating simple 3D text. I am fascinated by these logo design & I am not able to find any tutorial or demonstration for these kind of logo.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Do I need any other tool than PhotoShop to create logo's like below? or I can transform my simple logo to look like above?
I have created below logo based on existing logo but still can't make it look good

[image]

Comment: You can perfectly do that kind of images on Photoshop, but also you can do it in a 3D program like blender, which is free and very powerfull: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GeKhH1aaXuM

Comment: Also see: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/113783/how-to-mockup-a-logo-in-a-realistic-environment/113801#113801

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is a type of what's called a "mock-up", which is basically displaying how a design or logo would look like in a real world application. This is done to give the client an idea about how their logo would look like once it gets released and applied to real objects.

The types you mention specifically are for wall mounted signs (as on the entrance of buildings and such).

You can check [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20597/how-to-achieve-this-3d-card-effect?lq=1) answer for some tips on how to get started (although it's a different kind of mock-up, you can still learn something). You don't need anything other than photoshop to do these things.

Be aware that this is just for presentation purposes, and don't rely on it as the main logo design. You should have a working 2D vector design before you attempt to do this. So fix the basic shapes, text and colors first.

You can also google these designs now that you know the term, and study the source files (some of them you can download for free, like [the one you posted](http://graphicburger.com/3d-wall-logo-mockup-2/)), and try to understand how they were done. If there is anything specific you don't understand you can ask another question here.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. This really helped me. I am still wondering how these icons are made. I can play with Text but how to draw shape is still difficult. I would appreciate if you can redirect me right tutorial which can tell me how can I create shiny logo and the text in same color.. like in the question I have mentioned.

Comment: ZeroToInfinity, that is a separated question, how to draw shapes in a program vs. shiny material vs. 3D image. There are several steps there.

Comment: @Zerotoinfinity You're welcome, glad it helped! Just to be clear, when I said ask another question here, I meant create a separate question with the specific issue you are facing. If you have to create three separate questions, do it. But first make sure to search the site for any similar questions that might have been answered.