# How to merge all powerpoint slides into one 3D wireframe view similar to image attached

Tags: interface-design, information-graphics, mockup, microsoft-powerpoint, presentation-design

I want to make my presentation slides merge into one 3D view png file.

The image attached is how I would like my presentation slides to merge into one 3D view.

[image]

Comment: Anybody knows how the remedy? Are there any design softwares/ links i can use?

Comment: Save as PDF then open each page in illustrator, photoshop, imkscape etc then translate

Comment: See similar question [How to achieve this 3D “Card” effect](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20597/how-to-achieve-this-3d-card-effect).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to achieve this 3D "Card" effect](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20597/how-to-achieve-this-3d-card-effect)

Answer (score 1):

Seemingly quite few are interested in writing a full step by step tutorial for you. That's because making something in the same detail level is complex and writing a tutorial would be more like writing a book. Things become much closer the beginner level if you do not expect realistic

- card thickness which has curvature, gloss and image bent over the surface (=the visible vertical card edges either have zero thickness or they are approximated with simple lines)
- perspective; instead of it you accept a tilted parallel projection

With these simplifications you can work in any drawing program. I guess even MS Powerpoint will do if you have a modern version. I don't have one, so this is a guess. My images are drawn in Inkscape.

You must export your slides as PNGs or JPGs for easy manipulation. You import them to the drawing program. There you must also draw black rectangles of the same size. With reduced opacity and blur effect the rectangles can be used as shadows:

[image]

In the left there's an imported image. It's only a screenshot. In the right there's a drawn rectangle and it's blurred copy with reduced opacity. It's very useful for final composition if the blur and opacity can be changed like in Inkscape.

A card and its shadow can be made by applying three transformations: Skew (said also shear or slant in different programs), vertical scaling to lower height and rotation. Every piece need the same transformations for consistent look:

[image]

Fake thickness can be added by drawing 2 grey lines. The shadow side line is darker. The line ends are round and the lines are thin to hide the fact that the corners have false 3D projection:

[image]

The only thing that needs some extra thinking is how to make multiple shadows plausible:

[image]

The apparent elevation of the card affects 2 things: How much upper the card is than the shadow and how much the shadow is blurred. The card in lower elevation has less blurred shadow which looks thicker.

The upper card makes shadow on the lower card. The shadows and cards (edges too) must have right layering order. Special care is needed to mask the shadow on the lower card to cover only the card and make it to have less blur than the shadow on the floor because the distance is shorter. Its a separate blurred piece which has clipping path (=a copy of the card sized rectangle)

In the next image there's only the image (=no edge lines) of the lower card. In the left the shadow of the upper card is is in place and in the right the shadow is moved aside.

[image]

NOTE: The selection box in this program shows the unclipped size of the shadow.

And that's all. You must learn by yourself how to actually make the shown tricks with program commands and settings.